# How to setup Postfix for Ruby On Rails to send email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, postfix-mta

I want to have `postfix` to send email in my ROR project. As its safer and hax more functionality.

But now I'm quite lost. I installed `postfix`, got ROR working. But next what should I do?

(I only need to send email, not receive it at the moment)

Should I configure `postfix`, make it able to send email in comment line first, then integrate it into ROR?

If so, how should I set up the configure file in `postfix`, and how about settings in `rails`?

Or do I just need do every setting in `rails`? If so, what should be the detailed setting?

I'm quite confused. Lots of tutorials either are not working or do not suit my situation.

Answer (score 11):

Example Action Mailer Configuration

An example would be adding the following to your appropriate

config/environments/$RAILS_ENV.rb file:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
# Defaults to:
# config.action_mailer.sendmail_settings = {
#   location: '/usr/sbin/sendmail',
#   arguments: '-i -t'
# }
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default_options = {from: 'no-reply@example.com'}
```

More information: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

Comment: Just in case someone doesn't know: Postfix provides a compatible `sendmail` binary, so that's why this answer works.

Answer (score 1):

The one below works for me.
Paste the snippet in your `config/initializers/mail.rb` file:

```
ActionMailer::Base.sendmail_settings = {
        location: "/usr/sbin/sendmail",
        arguments: '-i -t'
}

ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :sendmail
ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true
ActionMailer::Base.raise_delivery_errors = true
ActionMailer::Base.default charset: "utf-8"
```